# Delete All Rows After a certain number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 5000 rows of data.  and I want to delete all the rows after 1000 how would I do this?

```
Delete from table
where *
limit 1000
```

is this correct?

Comment: Which database?  Oracle? Sql Server? MySql? other?

Comment: Do you care which rows get deleted, or can they just be any random rows as long as 4,000 get deleted?

Comment: And anything after the first 1000 rows

Comment: What defines 'first' - what is the criteria?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                row_number() OVER (ORDER BY some_column) AS rn
         FROM   TABLE)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE  rn > 1000
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM TABLE
WHERE ID NOT IN
(
   SELECT ID FROM TABLE LIMIT 1000
)
```

This query will :

1 - Select THE FIRST 1000 records from your database

2 - Deletes all the records that are not in the list of the first 100 records

Comment: SKIP is supported by the firebird DBMS, that was my bad.
Try OFFSET instead and let me know

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3214a/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( A ) AS
SELECT LEVEL
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5000;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3214a/2/0)**:

```
| COUNT(*) |
|----------|
|     5000 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
DELETE FROM test
WHERE A IN ( SELECT A FROM (SELECT A, ROWNUM rn FROM test ) WHERE rn > 1000 )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3214a/2/1)**:

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3214a/2/2)**:

```
| COUNT(*) |
|----------|
|     1000 |
```